First Profiler Frame Showing Over 900ms
My game I'm trying to upload to Apple is getting rejecting for crashing upon startup and I took it back into Unity for debugging. I discovered that the first frame of my profiler is reaching over 900ms on the other section! I don't know the steps to take to find out what scripts are getting over 900ms or how to fix this absurd value, I attempted to add a lagHandler script that loaded gameObject asynchronously, this is a picture of the profiler and the script I tried to make. The script did help a little by making the rest of the gameObjects load slightly later and more distributed but the first frame is still HUGE and I don't know how to fix the 900ms.
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class lagHandler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public List<GameObject> objectsToActivate;
        public float initialDelay = .5f; // Initial delay in seconds

        void Start()
        {
            StartCoroutine(ActivateObjects());
        }

        IEnumerator ActivateObjects()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(initialDelay); // Wait before starting activation

            foreach (GameObject obj in objectsToActivate)
            {
                obj.SetActive(true); // Activate the object
                yield return null; // Wait one frame before activating the next object
            }
        }
    }

Not sure what to fix now since I already took the verts down to about 50K and even without canvas animations it is slow.

Edit
I was testing out the profiler more and I disabled every single gameObject including the lagHandler and the profiler is still reaching over 900ms, this goes deeper and perhaps into the player settings, but I can't find out what it is at all.

I prefer to use Hierarchy mode rather than Timeline mode. It makes finding the bottleneck faster (at least, for me). Anyway, first of all, the editor is NOT the same as the actual build. You need to consider that. Second, trying to fix something without understanding what the actual bottleneck is makes no sense.

By the way, if the app crashes, the issue is most likely with memory rather than CPU. In case of taking too much CPU your app will lag. In case of taking too much memory, OS will kill the process.
